# Can We enable Notifications About Oracle Java Update In Linux?

Tags: java, notification, jdk, oracle

In windows we get Notification that newer java version is avaliable like this [image].

How Can I get the same Notifications about java in Linux.

Special for oracle jdk.I had Installed oracle Jdk by in this machine

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And by extracting tar file in /opt in other machine.

Also will package `oracle-java8-installer` will upgrade my java ?? Cause Last time when oracle-java8-installer upgraded it didn't download any tar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell (and have experienced), `oracle-java8-installer` will update your Java version for you.

Whenever a new version comes out, the installer is updated with the new information. The next time you run `sudo apt update`, this new installer version will be reflected. Running `sudo apt upgrade` will install the new installer, which will then (in turn) install the new version of Java.

Note that this will *only* work if you've installed Java through the package. If you used the raw tarball, this will not work nearly as well (or at all).

It is important to note, however, that this will not increase your "major" version (so Java 8 will never upgrade to Java 9, unless you install Java 9's installer).

This method of Java installation offers *no* notification, so you just need to run the `apt` updater. Depending on your system configuration, Ubuntu may offer a general update notification. See the **Software and Updates** app for this setting.

---

Generally speaking, very few packages installed through Apt will have their own update notification system (though some, especially launcher-only packages usually will). Instead, `apt` will take care of things and bundle it with all the other updates. To some, this centralized package system is one of the biggest benefits of Linux over other operating systems.

Comment: Last time when I `apt update && apt upgrade` .The installer did not download any tar file.

Comment: @SMITPATIL It's likely that the java 8 installer was not updated then, or the update was a bugfix instead of a new Java release. The [last version I see](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) is 8u144, updated 2017-08-02. This is also the latest version on the Java site.

Comment: thanks.Is there any way of seeing how the installer works ? ?

Comment: @SMITPATIL Yes. You can look at the DEB file itself. The install code itself is (I believe) in the post-install shell script contained. You can download the raw DEB files from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+packages). You may enjoy taking a look at the diffs - that tells you how the configs change between versions.